# change terminal title

Tags: bash, debian, terminal

I want to make a shell `alias` that starts a certain program and also changes the title of the terminal to the name of the program.  How can I do that?

In case it matters, I am running the terminal on Ubuntu and connecting to a Debian server via ssh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Bash, I use the following `trap` command in the last line of my `.bashrc`  to echo all commands to the titlebar.

```
# trap commands and echo them to xterm titlebar. Must be last line.
trap 'echo -ne "\033]0;$BASH_COMMAND $USER@${HOSTNAME}>$(pwd)\007"' DEBUG
```

So if you execute `sleep 10`, you will see your titlebar change to `sleep 10` for the duration of the command, after which it will change back to `user@host>pwd`.

Comment: And for zsh, see [Title and Hardstatus in the zsh wiki](http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/hardstatus).

Answer (score 7):

Most terminals recognize a certain escape sequence as an attempt to change the title, so this will work:

```
$ alias foo-with-title='echo -ne "\033]0;foo\007"; foo'
```

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: This works in a bare shell. Using tmux/byobu this doesn't seem to work. I also tried `bash -c 'echo -ne "\033]0;foo\007"'`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something similar to set titles on windows as I opened them because sometimes I have a big user interface on top of terminals and want to jump in and out of different windows.  I ended up defining a function in my `.bashrc` file because alias would not allow a parameter in the middle (if I understand correctly):

```
# Set the title for a terminal window:
# - first parameter is the title text
title() {
  echo -ne "\033]0;$1\007"
}
```

Then run it with `title foo`, which can be run on the command line or called by other commands.  This works for me on Debian using an Xfce terminal.