# Can't change gnome-terminal tab's title from within ssh session on remote debian 8 machine

Tags: debian, ssh, gnome-terminal

When I connect to a `debian 8` server I can't change `gnome-terminal` tab's title, see for yourself:

```
$ ssh deb6-server
$ echo -en '\e]0;test\a'
# title changes
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l

$ exit
$ ssh deb8-server
# here the title changes to USER@HOST: CWD
$ echo -en '\e]0;test\a'
# title doesn't change
$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND

$ echo -en '\e[0;34mtest\e[0m\n'
test   # written in blue
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid \n \l
```

And I don't really know where else to look. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you change the tab title while not in an SSH session?

Comment: Sure. I'm thinking if there's a way to sniff ssh traffic to see if my local machine is getting proper bytestream...

Comment: does `echo -en '\e]0;test\a'; sleep 10` change the title? You looked at `PROMPT_COMMAND` but not at `PS1`, the title could be changed by an escape sequence in `PS1`. What is the output of `echo "$PS1" | od -t x1`?

Comment: Indeed, you were right on the mark, it's `PS1` that is a culprit: `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ `. Not sure why you asked for a hexadecimal output. But I can provide you with it if it's still needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ESC ] 0` escape sequence works to change your terminal's title when you use it locally, it also works across SSH. SSH doesn't change the traffic between the application and the terminal.

If you run applications in a screen multiplexer such as screen or tmux, these do interpret escape sequences by themselves and send others to the terminal. That's independent of SSH, except inasmuch as you might be more inclined to use screen on a remote machine than locally.

The shell on the remote machine may well be configured to set the remote title whenever it starts to execute a command or whenever it displays a new prompt. This is usually done by printing the title-changing escape sequence as part of the prompt, so check the content of the `PS1` variable:

```
printf '%s\n' "$PS1" | cat -v
```

If the remote shell is bash, also check the `PROMPT_COMMAND` and the [`DEBUG` trap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/change-terminal-title/11233#11233):

```
echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"
trap -p DEBUG
```

If the remote shell is zsh, check `PS1`, `RPS1` (rare), and the `precmd` and `preexec` functions.

print -rl $PS1 $RPS1 $functions[precmd] $functions[preexec]