# How to set terminal's title with the first command?

Tags: bash, fedora

I have already write a function into the `.bashrc`, and it's also working for current. Anyway, it looks like:

```
function myserver() {
     ssh frank@192.168.1.10
}
```

and To visit my remote server I can easily run it on my command line:

```
myserver
```

But I have to manage different server at my computer, so many different remote server use the same terminal's title, same time it's really confusing me. My question is how can I set the terminal's title by the first command, which mean when I do `myserver1` and the title will be `myserver1` and when I do rest command it will no going to change anymore. When I open second terminal (total new one), and if I do `ls -la` , it's title will be `ls` or `ls -la` will be ok. How can I reach that?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11233/31256 "change terminal title") answer your question?

Comment: @ckujau I have tried it but doesn't work as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

@ckujau - no. offhand, that would be a terminal-specific feature (to set the title exactly once using escape sequences) which no one's implemented.  Some provide a feature where the terminal can be started with an unchangeable title.

Comment: Yes, I want to implement it as Xshell, which is Window's tool. but I can't find any suite way to reach that for now.

Comment: sorry - I've ignored xshell since it's a commercial product with few users, and no (freely-accessible) documentation.  Its manual would be the place to answer your question.  However, I see that [recently](https://www.netsarang.com/download/free_license.html) there's a free download to investigate.  But if it's NDA, it's moot.

Comment: Anyway, I found another way to distinguish it with `export PS1="\h:\W  "`. I use different emoji to each server. :P Thanks anyway

Comment: It won't work except for a special case.  For example, editors which set the title string are unaffected by that :-)